# phpMyAdmin/MySQL export users/priviledges for later import

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Is there a way to export priviledges/users out of phpMyAdmin version 3.3.9? And yes, in such format that later those could be imported into a new installation.

It would be good if database relations would be kept and so on.

If phpMyAdmin cannot handle it, MySQL command line solution will work too.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basically you want to dump some tables from `mysql` database, like `columns_priv`,`db`,`tables_priv` and `user`

As far as I remember phpmyadmin have configuration option to hide some databases, but you can access it by typing `?db=mysql` in url.

Comment: Nope. I tacked &db=mysql onto the export page, and imported the existing file into my new installation. No users were included.